# Restore my in app-purchases after app delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app and I want to know the best practices to restore user's purchased items if he deletes my app accidentally. For example if user has purchased some cars in my app and accidentally he deletes his app, how he can restore his purchases after he re installs the app.

Comment: Are these consumable or non-consumable purchases? For consumable purchases, there is no restore functionality unless you are tracking their user account "balance" on your own server.  For non-consumable purchases you must provide a restore button as per the in-app purchase programming guide

Comment: All are non-consumable

Comment: Then have you looked at the appropriate method in the Store Kit framework and the associated Apple documentation?  What is your specific question?

Comment: Keep in mind that your app will be rejected if you don't implement the restore functionality. Everything you need to know is documented in the framework of course.

Comment: Apple in their documentation says "When you create a new product to be sold in your store, you choose whether that product can be restored or not." Where i can make the the product as restore-able in itunes connect https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a button for it (Else Apple will reject your app)
When user re-install your app he can get those items back with that button.
Here is a code example for that button:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

Comment: Apple in their documentation says "When you create a new product to be sold in your store, you choose whether that product can be restored or not." Where i can make the the product as restore-able in itunes connect https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions

Comment: You are with but there are tons of app rejections because of that. Also user can try to buy the item that he already purchased. Apple will handle that operation and won't charge user once again. Here is the description about that:               Note: If the user attempts to purchase a product that’s already been purchased, rather than using your app’s restoration interface, the App Store creates a regular transaction instead of a restore transaction. The user isn’t charged again for the product. Treat these transactions the exact same way you treated the original transactions.

Comment: Okay but where i can mark my product restore-able in iTunes connect?

Comment: I am not sure if you should do something like that. Also I am not sure if this option even exists or not.

Comment: So do you mean that all non-consumable products are by default restore-able? I think there should be some way of doing this otherwise Apple didn't mention that in their documentation.

Comment: I posted Apple's note in previous comment. It says user won't be charged again and will be treated as original transactions. So I guess Apple will handle it if user does not use your app's restore interface. But as I said before restore purchase is a must for non consumables